# What is the collection version of SingleOrDefault for a Dictionary<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dictionary, extension-methods

Title kind of says it all.  I just can't seem to find a `DictionaryOrDefault` \ `ListOrDefault` \ `CollectionOrDefault` option.

Is there such a method?  If not how do I do this:

```
MyClass myObject = MyDictionary
    .SingleOrDefault(x =>
                        {
                            if (x.Value != null)
                                return (x.Value.Id == sourceField.SrcField.Id);
                            else
                                return false;
                        }).Key;
```

if there is more than one match?  (I am getting an execption because SingleOrDefault is only meant for single results (imagine that!).)

---

Guess I needed to be clearer (though the `where` answers looks good).

I have the above statement.  I changed my program so that it does not always return 1 (there can be several values that match one key).  That fails so I am looking for a collection to be returned (rather than just one item).

Comment: Little clarification here, you're trying to get many values that fit a predicate, or just one, whichever it is ?

Comment: "Title kind of says it all." Not really, what do you mean by `DictionaryOrDefault`? Please specify the expected semantics carefully, clearly and correctly.

Comment: so what you want is something that returns null if nothing matches, or a list if one or more does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `IEnumerable<T>.FirstOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate)` if your intention is to return the first one matching the predicate.

Otherwise you're simply looking at the `IEnumerable<T>.Where(Func<T, bool> predicate)` linq extension, which will return all elements that match the predicate passed. That will return an empty `IEnumerable<T>` if no elements match the predicate, at which point if you really need the value to be null, you can just look if anything is in it.

```
var res = MyDictionary.Where(x => 
                        { 
                            if (x.Value != null)  
                                return (x.Value.Id == sourceField.SrcField.Id);  

                            return false;  
                        });
if (!res.Any())
    res = null;
```

Then if you absolutly need to have it as a list, you can just call

```
res.ToList();
```

Note that if you're actually manipulating a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `res` will contain `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`'s.

Comment: I feel quite dumb for not thinking of Where.  I just got twisted around.

Answer (score 1):

if you do something like

```
var mylist = obj.Where(x=>x.attr1 == 4);
```

you can then check if anything was returned using the .Any() method

```
mylist.Any()
```

Comment: Don't call .ToList() until you need it.  Even if you know you need it right away, at least save it for the next line.

Comment: @Joel - Is there drawbacks calling ToList?  (I have assumed so, but never knew...)

Comment: Yes, there are drawbacks.  ToList() forces immediate iteration of the enumerable.  It breaks any advantage you might get from lazy evaluation.  By not calling ToList() you don't do _any_ real work until you actually use the enumerable somewhere like in a foreach.

Comment: A good example is John's code above.  ToList() forces you to iterate over the entire collection, even though the Any() method only cares if there's one and can stop after the first item in the sequence.